# How to read values of Sent, Received, Lost, Maximum, Minimum and Average from ping result using regular expression and pwoershell

Tags: regex, powershell, networking

How to read values of Sent, Received, Lost, Maximum, Minimum and Average from ping result using regular expression and Powershell.

I have following code written but gives entire line as in output

```
$HostIP = ping relay2.ecs.co.uk
$HostIP -match '(?<Average> = (\d+))*(?<Sent> = (\d+))*(?<Received> = (\d+))'
```

Output:

```
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Minimum = 156ms, Maximum = 157ms, Average = 156ms
```

Expected out is like:

```
4,4,0,0%,156ms,157ms,Average156ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell has Test-Connection for this purposes, but you can also parse ping command:

```
#test data
$pingResult = 'Pinging mySite.com [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=69ms TTL=47
 Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=70ms TTL=47
 Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=69ms TTL=47
 Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=69ms TTL=47
Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
 Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
 Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
 Minimum = 69ms, Maximum = 70ms, Average = 69ms'

$m = [Regex]::Matches($pingResult, 'TTL=(?<TTL>\d+)[\s\S]*?Sent = (?<Sent>\d+).+?Received = (?<Received>\d+).+?Lost = (?<Lost>\d+) \((?<LossPct>\d+%)[\s\S]*?Minimum = (?<Min>\d+ms).+?Maximum = (?<Max>\d+ms).+?Average = (?<Avg>\d+ms)').Captures.Groups
@{
    TTL = $m['TTL'].Value;
    Sent = $m['Sent'].Value;
    Received = $m['Received'].Value;
    Lost = $m['Lost'].Value;
    Min = $m['Min'].Value;
    Max = $m['Max'].Value;
    Avg = $m['Avg'].Value;
}
```

---

In addition, example of Test-Connection:

```
Test-Connection www.google.com | measure -Property ResponseTime -Average -Maximum -Minimum
```

TTL is set by sender (`-TimeToLive` argument), number of tries depends on `-Count` argument (defaults to 4).

More complex example, using objects and pipelining:

```
$tries = 4 #how many tries
$ttl = Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 255 #TTL iss set by sender randomly from 1 to 255
Test-Connection www.google.com -TimeToLive $ttl -Count $tries -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | `
    Measure-Object -Property ResponseTime -Average -Maximum -Minimum | `
    % { [PSCustomObject]@{
            TTL = $ttl
            Sent = $tries
            Received = $result.Count;
            Lost = $tries-$result.Count;
            Min = $result.Minimum;
            Max = $result.Maximum;
            Avg = $result.Average;
        }
    } | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

**Result**

```
TTL Sent Received Lost Min Max   Avg
--- ---- -------- ---- --- ---   ---
169    4        4    0  17  23 18,75
```

---

To get one line string:

```
$result = Test-Connection www.google.com -Count $tries -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$stats = $result | Measure-Object -Property ResponseTime -Average -Maximum -Minimum
if ($result) {
    "$tries,$($result.Count),$($tries-$result.Count),$(100*($tries-$result.Count)/$tries)%,$($stats.Minimum)ms,$($stats.Maximum)ms,$([int]$stats.Average)ms,$($result[0].ResponseTimeToLive)"
}

#returns
#4,4,0,0%,17ms,17ms,17ms,49
```

Comment: Thank you. Great help! I tried the same code to retrieve value of TTL from below line 
Reply from 74.125.200.94: bytes=32 time=64ms TTL=44 
but no go, Any help?

Thank you again.

Comment: Updated answer to capture TTL.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried with Test-Connection www.google.com | Select *, it does not shows the values for Sent, Received, Lost, Maximum, Minimum, out of curiosity, do you know any code with Test-Connection which will allow to get the same values. or any hint?

Comment: Included `Test-Connection` example.

Comment: Sorry. The latest example does not work. It does not give values for MIN, MAX and average though the syntax is same like you gave as a first sample. Also TTL value is wrong, How would I read value of ResponseTimeToLeave (this is required one),  I am also trying to read values in one line like 169, 4, 4, 0, 17, 23

Comment: Added another one.

Comment: Tried but failed on PS5, succeed on PS4. Tried troubleshooting but no go. 
I am getting an error says powershell 5.0 Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Count'. the argument is null and empty.

Answer (score 1):

That's expected. `ping` produces array of strings, `-match` operating on arrays will return any element of the array that matches regex provided:

```
@(
    'dog'
    'cat'
    'owl'
) -match 'o'
dog
owl
```

Also: your regular expression is somewhat broken. It will never capture any group other than 'received' and 2, but capturing 'sent' there. What you need is something that looks at output, not named captures:

```
$output | ForEach-Object { 
    if ($_ -match 'Sent = (\d+).*Received = (\d+).*Lost = (\d+) \((\d+%)') { 
        $sent = $Matches[1]
        $received = $Matches[2]
        $lost = $Matches[3]
        $percent = $Matches[4]
    } elseif ($_ -match 'Minimum = (\d+ms).*Maximum = (\d+ms).*Average = (\d+ms)') {
        $min = $Matches[1]
        $max = $Matches[2]
        $avg = $Matches[3]    

    }
}
"$sent,$received,$lost,$percent,$min,$max,$avg"
```

Using syntax `(?<Name>regex)` is only useful if you want to look at `$Matches.Name`. It's often the case that you can use `$Matches` to create objects with properties straight away. I blogged about it [here](https://becomelotr.wordpress.com/2013/01/07/quick-tip-matches-is-enough/).

Comment: Great help mate! That's working. I have just appended another else if to get the value of TTL from below line, but I dont get the value of TTL, 
Reply from 74.125.200.94: bytes=32 time=64ms TTL=44

here is the code,

$output = ping relay2.ecs.co.uk

$output | ForEach-Object { 
     
    } elseif ($_ -match 'TTL = (\d+)') {
        $ttl = $Matches[1]

    }
}
"$sent,$received,$lost,$percent,$min,$max,$avg,$ttl"